# How is the correct way multithreaded user programs (or multiple processes) to access a device?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, device-driver, file-descriptor

I am creating user programs that access a device driver. 
Multiple threads must open the device? (each thread has a file descriptor of the device itself). Or can be opened from the principal and all the threads get a copy of the file descriptor?

What happens to the atomicity in access to the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread in Linux as a process is created via the system call `clone`. From its [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) :

```
 If CLONE_FILES is set, the calling process and the child
          process share the same file descriptor table.  Any file
          descriptor created by the calling process or by the child
          process is also valid in the other process.  Similarly, if one
          of the processes closes a file descriptor, or changes its
          associated flags (using the fcntl(2) F_SETFD operation), the
          other process is also affected.

          If CLONE_FILES is not set, the child process inherits a copy
          of all file descriptors opened in the calling process at the
          time of clone().  (The duplicated file descriptors in the
          child refer to the same open file descriptions (see open(2))
          as the corresponding file descriptors in the calling process.)
          Subsequent operations that open or close file descriptors, or
          change file descriptor flags, performed by either the calling
          process or the child process do not affect the other process.
```

Assuming that you are using a library to create a thread like *pthread*. Threads created with `pthread_create` share the file descriptors with all other threads in the process (not just the parent). This cannot be changed. While process created with `fork` get a copy of the file descriptor. You must notice that sharing a file descriptor and having a copy are two different things. If you have a copy ( for example created with `fork`) then all copies must be closed before the file handler is definitely closed. If a file descriptor is shared among different threads, once one thread closes it, this file descriptor  will be closed for all thread.  Similarly, if one of the processes changes its associated flags (using the `fcntl`), the other process is also affected.

Comment: So... in the main of the application it opens the device and everything works fine ...
What do you say of the flags at the opening? NONBLOCK, SYNC ...

Comment: If the fd is shared, it will be the same for all threads. If you change it in one thread, the change affects also the  other thread. Note, this is different if the fd is copied.